# Horizontal scroll to, with wordpress acf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am searching for a way of scrolling horizontally to my column of content.
On the click of a column, i'd like it to move to the left.
[I made a picture to explain better.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTMMa.jpg)

The thing is : i am working with ACF flexible content, and I haven't found a way of combining this with some javascript library like [Sly](http://darsa.in/sly/) don't work. Because this one is working with *ul list*...
How to implement this "scroll to" effect ?

```css
.article-atelier {
  width: 300px;
  height: 85vh;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  padding: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: none;
}
.article-atelier:hover {
  background-color: gray
}
#ateliers-hori {
  width: 7000px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 85vh;
}
.titrage {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80vh;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.titrage2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<?php define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false); require( './wp-load.php'); ?>

<?php /* Template Name: ateliers */ ?>


<?php get_header(); ?>



<div id="content">


  <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
  <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


  <div id="ateliers-hori">

    <div class="titrage">
      <h4 class="titrage2"><?php the_field('titre_1'); ?></h4>
    </div>

    <?php // check if the flexible content field has rows of data if( have_rows( 'ateliers') ): ?>

    <?php while ( have_rows( 'ateliers') ) : the_row(); ?>


    <?php if( get_row_layout()=='atelieratelier' ):?>

    <div class="article-atelier">
      <h4 class="titrage2"><?php the_sub_field('atelier_01');?></h3>
               <?php the_sub_field('texte_atelier');?>
               </div>


             <?php  endif;?>




          <?php  endwhile;?>

       <?php else :?>

          // no layouts found

      <?php endif;

      ?>




 <div class="titrage"><?php the_field('titre_2'); ?></div>




 <?php

 // check if the flexible content field has rows of data
 if( have_rows('ateliers') ):?>

    <?php while ( have_rows('remise_a_niveau') ) : the_row();?>

        <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'remiseaniveau' ):?>

       


         <div class="article-atelier">
           <h4 class="titrage2"> <?php the_sub_field('titre_remise');?></h4>
      <?php the_sub_field( 'texte_remise');?>
    </div>

    <?php endif;?>

    <?php endwhile;?>

    <?php else :?>// no layouts found

    <?php endif; ?>



    <?php endwhile; ?>

  </div>


  <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/searchform.php"); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

</div>
<!-- fermeture div "page" -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a front-end development task, so no need to show us the PHP.

Have you tried using jQuery? Here is a quick example of something according to your image:

```js
$('.article').on('click', function () {

    $('html, body').animate({

        scrollLeft: $(this).offset().left + 'px'

    }, 1000);
    
    $('.article').removeClass('select');
    
    $(this).addClass('select');

});
```

```css
body {
    width: 1100px;
}
.article {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.article:hover, .article.select {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article"></div>
<div class="article"></div>
<div class="article"></div>
<div class="article"></div>
<div class="article"></div>
<div class="article"></div>
<div class="article"></div>
<div class="article"></div>
<div class="article"></div>
<div class="article"></div>
```

Press 'Run Code Snippet' above or have a look at the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/y8wbv98n/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. But it seems like this code doesn't work on Firefox. I'm still searching for a way to integrate it in my wordpress...

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked. I included your javascript code in the loop, at the end of the flexible content.